# What factors determine the selection of a specific type of MC move?

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, monte-carlo, atomistic-simulation

There are several types of Monte Carlo (MC) moves that can be used in simulations:

1. **Metropolis-Hastings**: a sampling technique used to generate a Markov chain of states with desired probabilities by accepting or rejecting proposed moves based on an acceptance probability.
2. **Single Particle Displacement**: In this move, a single particle's position is randomly selected, and a small displacement is applied. The displacement can be along one or more dimensions.
3. **Particle Exchange**: This move involves exchanging the positions of two randomly selected particles.
4. **Particle Insertion/Deletion**: This move involves adding or removing a particle from the system.
5. **System Scaling**: In this move, the entire system is rescaled by a random factor. It can be used to simulate changes in density or to explore different system sizes.
6. **Cluster Moves**: Cluster moves involve treating a group of particles as a single entity and moving them collectively.
7. **Rotations**: Rotational moves involve rotating the orientation of a particle or a group of particles.
8. etc.

My question is, how do I know when to use which move? I.e. what factors determine the selection of a specific type of move?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you've learned anything more about this since asking your question?

Comment: @NikeDattani, Not much. I use Replica Exchange Monte Carlo  (REMC) because my professor uses it.

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor to write an answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani, Coz, I don't want to mix my real world life with my web-life.

Comment: My advice is to embrace the fact that it will happen sooner or later whether you like it or not: I was user1271772 for about 10 years before a moderator at Quantum Computing Stack Exchange revealed who I was (they use cookies, IP addresses and such to identify users), and then I wished I had just used my real name from the beginning (but the reasons might not be clear to you or anyone else until it happens).